# Visual Studio 2022 C# - $(ProgramFiles) in csproj HintPath does not pick up ProgramFiles (x86)

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I'm putting together a machine to build existing projects, which currently runs Visual Studio 2022.

This is having issues building legacy .CSPROJ files that use $(ProgramFiles) in the HintPath to point at references.

I can't update these projects or any of the pipelines that run them - what's the best way to let the machine know that $(ProgramFiles) can also mean C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: Borken environment probably, type `set` at the command prompt to verify.

Comment: Do you have references used from both `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` in the same project? That will be a big problem. The `$(ProgramFiles)` property can only have one value.

Comment: [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022) with names that are valid for MSBuild properties, will be available in MSBuild as properties with the same name. The `ProgramFiles` environment variable is mapped to the `$(ProgramFiles)` property. `ProgramFiles(x86)` is not a valid property name but MSBuild provides the `$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)` property.